# Aggregate and calculate total minutes for set of records as productivity

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table that lists activity for people and start / end timed for activity.
How do I get total amount of records for each person?

```
SELECT NAME,
    --sum(startDT- endDT) AS minutes -- stuck here
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY NAME
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subtracting end time from start time, which will produce a negative value - try flipping those around (subtract start time from end time). The following will give you the number of records and the total elapsed time for each NAME:

```
SELECT NAME,
       COUNT(*) AS "Records for NAME",
       TO_CHAR(NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(END_DATE_TIME - START_DATE_TIME), 'DAY')) AS MINUTES
  FROM TABLE1
  GROUP BY NAME
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d75b/12)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `startDT` and `endDT` are both of type `date`, you were really close.  Subtracting two dates gives a difference in days.  Multiply by 24 to get a difference in hours and again by 60 to get minutes

```
SELECT NAME,
       sum(endDT - startDT)*24*60 AS minutes -- stuck here
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY NAME
```

Assuming that your differences aren't always an exactly even number of minutes, you'll either get a non-integer result (e.g. 12.5 for 12 minutes 30 seconds) here or you'll want to either `round` or `trunc` the sum to get an integer number of minutes.